# Ansible: Finding matching pattern shows error in regex expression

Tags: ansible

I got stuck in this small thing. I have to read a file, *myfile.txt*, which content is about user id and password info. It's kind of *.properties* files which stores key value pair and it's used in Java related technologies to store the configurable application.

I have to split it in such a way that:

*myfile.txt*

```
mysql.user=abc
mysql.user.one=abc
user=abc
```

It should split where ever it finds **`user` and `=` sign** such as

1. string before `=` which contains `user` becomes `idhead`
2. string after `=` becomes `idval`

I'm giving you an example for first scenario how it should happen:

```yaml
idhead: mysql.user
idval: abc
```

There may be **3 scenarios** of entries in the file as mentioned above.

```yaml
    - name: Fetch the first file
      slurp:
        src: /home/usr/Desktop/files/myfile.txt
      register: file1
    - name: extract content for matching pattern user & userid value
      set_fact:
        idinfo: "{{ file1['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall((\user+)(=.*=))}}"
    - name: set fact for id head 
      set_fact:
        idhead: "{{item.split('=')[0]}}"
      loop: "{{idinfo}}"
    - name: set fact for id val
      set_fact:
        idval: "{{item.split('=')[1]}}"
      loop: "{{idinfo}}"
```

It shows a regex expression error, however when I check in https://regex101.com/, it's matching the expression. Is it some Ansible thing or am I missing out something? I'm not getting this. Please suggest me with the possible answers for regex expressions in all three scenarios.

Comment: Do I understand properly at your regexp trial that you could have a file with value like `user          =did you expect spaces before that equal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really have to go in such complexity neither do you have to do multiple `set_fact`.

You could approach it in a really simply and naive way just looping on your content and skipping the lines that do not match your requested behaviour with a simple [`when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement), use this in combination with [`with_lines`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/lines.html) test and a simple [`in`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#in) and your use case could end up being a single task:

```yaml
## 
# Mind that you will be constantly overriding those two facts,
# so maybe you should construct an array with those?
# See the full working playbook below for an example
##
- set_fact:
    idhead: "{{ item.split('=')[0] | trim }}"
    idval: "{{ item.split('=')[1] | trim }}"
  with_lines: cat /home/usr/Desktop/files/myfile.txt
  when: "'user' in item and '=' in item"
```

*myfile.txt*

```
mysql.user=abc
mysql.user.one=abc
user=abc
foo=bar
some.user.foo         =       bar
```

Working playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        idhead: "{{ idhead | default([]) + [item.split('=')[0] | trim] }}"
        idval: "{{ idval  | default([]) + [item.split('=')[1] | trim] }}"
      with_lines: cat /home/usr/Desktop/files/myfile.txt
      when: item | regex_search('.*user.*=')

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ idhead }} {{ idval }}"
```

Gives the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=mysql.user=abc)
ok: [localhost] => (item=mysql.user.one=abc)
ok: [localhost] => (item=user=abc)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=foo=bar) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=some.user.foo         =       bar)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "['mysql.user', 'mysql.user.one', 'user', 'some.user.foo'] ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'bar']"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Now for your regex, it is indeed invalid, as `\u` in your `\user` [is an invalid token](https://regex101.com/r/ajgUft/2).

And I guess what you meant was to look for [`.*user.*=.*`](https://regex101.com/r/ajgUft/3):

Given the same *myfile.txt* as above, this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - slurp:
        src: /home/usr/Desktop/files/myfile.txt
      register: file1
    - set_fact:
        idinfo: "{{ file1['content'] | b64decode | regex_findall('.*user.*=.*') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ idinfo }}"
```

Gives the recap

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************

TASK [slurp] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "mysql.user=abc",
        "mysql.user.one=abc",
        "user=abc",
        "some.user.foo         =       bar"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually works. I guess I messed up a bit in regex. Yeah arrays would actually be easier if both are getting used in single task. Also, I think slurp works well when the file is in remote machine. In the first case, it shows some lookup plugin error maybe because it's not in command.